# Capturing specific Status Change Date from Each group in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to Capture specific Status Change Date from Each group and show them in a single row.PFB snapshot of the requirement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm0Cy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have basic SQL knowledge but try my best, please verify and review.
code for MS SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [data] (package NVARCHAR(250), status NVARCHAR(250), date  NVARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO data (package,status,date)
SELECT 'sony', 'register', 'D1' UNION
SELECT 'sony', 'renew', 'D2' UNION
SELECT 'sony', 'cancel', 'D3' UNION
SELECT 'starSports', 'register', 'D3' UNION
SELECT 'starSports', 'renew', 'D4' UNION
SELECT 'starSports', 'modified', 'D5'


WITH cte_data
AS (
SELECT package,
        (CASE WHEN status = 'register'    THEN [date] ELSE '' END) AS register_date,
        (CASE WHEN status = 'renew'    THEN [date] ELSE '' END) AS renew_date
FROM data )
select t.package, t.register_date, d.renew_date
from cte_data t
INNER JOIN cte_data d ON d.package = t.package
where t.register_date<>'' AND d.renew_date <>''
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from your_table
pivot (any_value(date) Date for status in ('Register', 'Renew'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]